# websockets.sync.client - No module named 'websockets.sync'

Tags: python, websocket

I am looking at websockets and have tried the official docs here: https://pypi.org/project/websockets/

I do a `pip install websockets` to make sure that I have the latest module.

I then run the template code (from the official docs) below:

```py
import asyncio
from websockets.sync.client import connect

def hello():
    with connect("ws://localhost:8765") as websocket:
        websocket.send("Hello world!")
        message = websocket.recv()
        print(f"Received: {message}")

hello()
```

But my linter throws two errors:

1. `import asyncio` is never used.
2. `websockets.sync.client` throws `No module named 'websockets.sync'`

So, I tried changing to this:

```py
from websockets.client import connect
def hello():
    with connect("ws://localhost:8765") as websocket:
        websocket.send("Hello world!")
        message = websocket.recv()
        print(f"Received: {message}")

hello()
```

But got this error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'Connect' object does not support the context manager protocol
```

So, what is the correct way of implementing a basic websocket (and are the official docs correct) ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though the code does work.

Needed to do a `pip install --upgrade websockets` to force the upgraded version.

And confirm the version with

```
python -m websockets --version
```

It seems as though the `import asyncio` line is not necessary (websocket works without it).